# SVG align on the right

Tags: html, text, svg

I am trying to justify multiple lines of svg text to the right but the last line of text is always farther to the right and I can't figure out why.

The important stuff.

```html
<svg style="border:1px solid blue;" text-anchor="end">
    <text font-size="30px">
        <tspan x="100%" dy="30">tspan line 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="100%" dy="35">tspan line 2</tspan>
        <tspan x="100%" dy="35">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCuSa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for SVG text is to compress whitespace. That means all space at the beginning and end of text is removed and in the middle is compressed to a single space.

You have whitespace around each `<tspan>` element. The whitespace before the first  and after the last `<tspan>` is removed so the last `<tspan>` goes all the way to the right. The whitespace after the second  is only compressed to a space (note that the newline becomes whitespace too) so the middle line is actually "tspan line 2 "

If you remove all the whitespace between the > and the < characters it will display as you want it to.